# Is is possible to analyze the "aggregate" impact of multiple sequential interventions on a time series within the framework of CausalImpact?

Tags: causalimpact, bsts

Is there a way to analyze the "aggregate" impact of multiple sequential interventions on a time series within the framework of CausalImpact, using the same set of control variables (predictor series) for all interventions?

Imagine that I have three sequential (complementary) interventions occurring one after the other at time points t1, t2, and t3 (where t3 > t2 > t1). Instead of conducting three separate CausalImpact analyses using three sets of pre and post-intervention periods, I want to determine whether the three interventions, considered together, had a significant causal impact on the behavior of the time series (in the post-intervention periods), while accounting for the specificities of each intervention.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.